# Javascript - Remove cursor position in input field

Tags: javascript, html

How would you remove the ability to change cursor position in an input field. So when a user types, they will always type at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might hit some old browser limitations with this one, but just to get you an idea.
You'll need to handle both `paste` and `keydown` events. For the *paste* you might need the Clipboard API to the rescue. Enough talking, here it goes:

```js
function setRng(el, txt, from, to) {
  el.setSelectionRange(from + txt.length, to + txt.length);
}

function insVal(el, txt, from, to) {
  from = Math.max(0, from);
  to = to || from;
  el.value = el.value.substring(0, from) + txt + el.value.substring(to, el.value.length);
  setRng(el, txt, from, from);
}

function writeToEnd(ev) {
  var el = ev.target;
  var key = ev.keyCode;
  var isBackspace = key === 8;
  var isPaste = ev.type === "paste";
  var txt = isPaste ? (ev.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text') : '';
  var fromOffset = isBackspace ? -1 : 0;
  
  if (txt && txt.length > 1 || isPaste || isBackspace) ev.preventDefault(); // Cause of some special input
  insVal(el, txt, el.value.length + fromOffset, el.value.length);
}

[...document.querySelectorAll('.writeToEnd')].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('keydown', writeToEnd);
  el.addEventListener('paste', writeToEnd);
});
```

```html
<input class="writeToEnd" type="text" value="input test"><br>
<textarea class="writeToEnd">textarea test</textarea><br>
(Test also COPY/PASTE using mouse and keyboard)
```

[MDN Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API),
[Stack Overflow get-clipboard-data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6804718/383904)

Comment: Thanks! It works great. I didn't think of the copy/paste. There is only a small bug. It doesn't work with backspace. Otherwise this has been the best answer thanks!

Comment: Sorry for bugging you again. When you hit backspace, it removes two characters instead of one.

Comment: @Tim sorry when refactoring the code I forgot to add `|| isBackspace`

Answer (score 1):

This code will not stop user from changing the position of cursor but it won't allow user to write in between the text.

Please try this

```js
function writeAtLast() {
            var textbox = document.getElementById('text');
            textbox.setSelectionRange(textbox.value.length, textbox.value.length);
        };
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" class="txtbox" onkeypress='writeAtLast()' onCopy="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false" onPaste="writeAtLast()" autocomplete=off />
```

Comment: You forgot that one can use `copy / paste`? Also, please, teach people to use `Element.addEventListener()`. Also, querying the DOM on every single keystroke is such a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for the information,  we can try blocking paste on the text box. Let me edit it. Will check on addEventListerner too

Comment: Block? Why? I'd instead simply try to improve the necessary code to achieve the desired without destroying user experience.

Comment: Changed it to handle the paste scenario to paste also at last of the text.

Comment: You just destroyed classic copy/paste functionality :\

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan can you please share some details what should have been done to handle this. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176967/discussion-between-ashu-and-roko-c-buljan).

Answer (score -1):

```js
function changeCursorPosition() {
  var ele = document.getElementById('txt');
  //set cursor position here
  ele.setSelectionRange(1, 1);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeypress="changeCursorPosition()" />
```