# Uncaught TypeError: item.getData is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, clipboarddata

I want to paste the clipboard content on html page. The content is copied from an ms-word file. Contains text and images. Consider the following code:

```
<div id="pasteArea" contenteditable="True"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pasteArea = document.getElementById('pasteArea');
    pasteArea.onpaste = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
        for (index in items) {
            var item = items[index];
            if(item.kind === 'string'){
                console.log(item.getData('text'));
                // Getting the error in here!
            }
            else if(item.kind === 'file'){
                // Code for handling images
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I tried using `event.clipboardData.getData('text');` but it fetches the entire text (i.e. skips the images in between) and also the text formatting is lost.

Any idea on how to handle the above case? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl i had a look on that as well, but the solutions are using `event.clipboardData.getData('text');` and i want to get the individual text part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for getAsString which requires a callback to process the clipboard.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/getAsString

```js
const pasteArea = document.getElementById('pasteArea');

pasteArea.onpaste = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const { items } = event.clipboardData;
  for (const item of items) processClipboard(item)
}

const processClipboard = item => {
  if (item.kind === 'string' && item.type === 'text/plain') {

    item.getAsString(s => console.log(s))

  }
}
```

```css
div { background-color: #ccc; }
```

```html
<div id="pasteArea" contenteditable="True">Paste something here</div>
```

Comment: This works, but along with the copied text, it also prints out some html and rtf text.

Comment: you can add  && item.type === 'text/plain'

Comment: This works perfectly but the text formatting is lost, like bold, italics, subscript, etc. I tried using `<pre>` tags but still not working. Thank you.

Comment: Dude you can't have both xD remove html and having styling pick one

Comment: I tried out using `item.type === 'text/html'` the formatting is maintained and i get the text I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your item is of type [DataTransferItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem) so you should use getAsString() to retrieve the text of the item;

This function takes a callback function as first argument : 
`item.getAsString(str => console.log(str));`

Comment: This works, but along with the copied text, it also prints out some html and rtf text

Comment: If you want to delete those HTML tags you'll need to do further processing of the text, because HTML is treated as text. You can strip all tags with a regex like `str.replace(/<\/?([^>]+)>/g, "")`

Comment: I tried out using `item.type === 'text/html'`  and then printing it within an html element. Now the formatting is maintained and I get the text I need. Thank you