# Can not fetch data from input field?

Tags: javascript

When we paste data in input field, we can not fetch data from input field, it's always show blank;

```js
function myFunction() {
      console.log(document.getElementById("inpt").innerText);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("inpt").innerText;
}
```

```html
<input id="inpt"  type="text" onpaste="myFunction()" value="Try to paste something in here" size="40">
    
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)

Comment: Are you sure you are using ANgular?

Comment: @Adrita Sharm  same problem happen in angular also.

Comment: You could try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19269040/3918612

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Angular, try this:

Template:

```
<input id="inpt"  type="text" (paste)="myFunction($event)" value="Try to paste something in here" size="40">
```

TS:

```
myFunction(event: ClipboardEvent) {
      let clipboardData = event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
      let pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text');
      console.log(pastedText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `setTimeout` function for that.

```js
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById('inpt').value;
    })
}
```

```html
<input id="inpt"  type="text" onpaste="myFunction()" value="abc abc" size="40">
    
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: you didnt add the reason as to why