# Paste from clipboard working on browser but not on extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

I am working on an extension made on react, and the paste from the clipboard function is working fine in the browser but not working on the extension. Code I am using:

```
async function onPasteHandler(): Promise<void> {
   const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
   console.log("text", text);
   setValue(text);
 }
```

Comment: Assuming this is a listener for `paste` event, you should read the event's clipboardData directly: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling that function in content_scripts js file only, if you want to work in your extension as well then you must be calling it in your popup.html file as well. It's because content_script, background_script, and popup files work in complete isolation and are independent of each other.