# Are html text inputs able to have multiple lines like the text area element

Tags: html

all. I'm curious to know if the regular text input (not text area) could detect multiple lines value. If I copy any string that has various lines and pastes it into a standard input box, it will display as a single-line string and has no idea whether it has multiple lines or a single line.

I just want to know if we can preserve the original value (with multiple lines)

Original string value

```
INVOICE_500
INVOICE_501
```

After pasting it into the regular text input

```
INVOICE_500 INVOICE_501
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the regular input type=text is one line only. All you can do is add a paste event listener so that anytime the value will change because of pasting, it will be stored inside a data attribute so you will preserve the original value.

Answer (score 1):

I found an article from a previous post where an way has been shown. We can use clipboard API as it copy text as it was written. It was applied on a div. I have converted it on a input field. I have attached the code below. Hope this might help you.

Reference article: [Clipboard data on paste event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser/6804718#6804718)

```js
function handlePaste(e) {
  var clipboardData, pastedData;

  // Stop data actually being pasted into input
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get pasted data via clipboard API
  clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

  // Do whatever with pasteddata
  alert(pastedData);
}

document.getElementById('pasteInput').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

```html
<input id='pasteInput' placeholder='Paste text here'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, the only HTML input element that's designed to be multi-line is the "textarea" element.

```
<textarea name="textArea" cols="40" rows="5">
```