# Cannot get text out of a paste event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, event-handling, copy-paste, paste

I'm trying to develop a function that can manipulate pasted text before it reaches the textbox.

My current issue is that no data is gathered when this code is ran in Firefox.

```
document.getElementById("myTextBox").addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
    console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('text')) 
  });
```

From my testing this only works in Chrome and Edge. In Firefox it returns a empty string.

My Firefox version is 115.02 (64bit)

I have also viewed most of the questions on Stack Overflow that pertain to this question.

Ive tried bitwise OR'ing like this (window.clipboardData||e.clipboardData)

This didnt work on Firefox either.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to all those that answered but none of the solutions work so I will be attaching a codepen to recreate the issue

https://codepen.io/Jimmy-Gore/pen/VwVmzVV?editors=1111

This pen demonstrates the issue, as no text will show up in the console.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It works in Firefox for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser

Comment: @epascarello Unfortunately I already tried this post

Answer (score 1):

Try OR again, but with switched values:

```js
document.getElementById("myTextBox").addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
    console.log((e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text')) 
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you look at the recent edit in which I attached a Code Pen to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching the event listener to `window` object instead of the actual element:

```js
window.addEventListener('paste', e => {
    console.log((e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text')) 
});
```