# jQuery: detect pasting into a WYSIWYG editor

Tags: jquery, html, editor, detect, pasting

I'm using htmlarea for my little [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system), and I was wondering if it's possible to detect if something gets pasted into it with jQuery?

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an Event Listener to your textarea for "keydown,"
and then looking out for keyCode == 86, that's the paste event.
Now you can do whatever you want to happen when a user tries to paste.

Like this:

```
document.getElementById('YOURhtmlArea').addEventListener('keydown', 
function (foo)
{
     if (foo.keyCode == 86)
     {
          alert('SOMEONE IS PASTING');
          foo.preventDefault();
     }
});
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: What happens if they use the mouse to paste text into the area?

Comment: Not sure how, but ckEditor handles this. You could start tearing apart their code, it is open source.