# Detecting html textarea's change

Tags: jquery, events, textarea

I'd like to monitor my textarea's changes with jQuery. I can do this with the keyup event and it works perfectly. But what event I can get when a user click on the textarea (right mouse click), then choose paste?

Click event occur only when the user click with the left mouse button on the textarea.

How can I handle this situation?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input

Comment: yeah, sorry. But thanks, because I found the right answer there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can detect Pastes or Cuts into the textarea by:

```
$("#TextBox1").bind('paste', function(e) {
            alert('pasting text!');
        });
$("#TextBox1").bind('cut', function(e) {
            alert('cut text!');
        });
```

Or combine:

```
$("#Text1").bind('cut paste', function(e) {
    alert(e.type + ' text!');
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. But it's close, so I'll accept it. The right answer : $("#TextBox1").bind('input paste', function(e) {...});

Comment: I used just `...bind("input cut paste"...` and it works like a charm - typing, cut & paste using the keyboard or context menu; even drag/drop of text.