# using Rangy.js to paste plain text without HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, paste, rangy

I tied to search and search around here and Google, But i not found any solution to do it so simple via using [Rangy.js](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) or native JS.

If I have simple formatted text to copy like..

```
<div>
    <b>Copy me (All) : Soufflé chupa chups</b><br>
    <p style="color:#f00;">
        Cotton candy caramels
    </p>
</div>
```

How can I copy and paste plain text (without styled text) to `contenteditable` element ?

I dont care about older IEs. Just current Firefox or Chrome need to work.

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/72r6J/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll need a slightly hacky solution. I've described it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3554615/96100

Here's a helpful in-depth answer to a similar question by a CKEditor developer:

[Paste as plain text Contenteditable div & textarea (word/excel...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240602/paste-as-plain-text-contenteditable-div-textarea-word-excel/11290082#11290082)

Comment: Ok, I do it so simple in my case. Just remove inline style http://jsbin.com/eqiyuv/1/edit

Answer (score -1):

I don't know all your use cases, but what about something like this:

```
$(document).keyup(function(){
         $(".editor").text($(".editor").text());
    });
```

It simply removes all html tags inside, you can also do it with other events, or with removing all style attributes inside editor div.