# TextArea Auto Resize On Paste

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, here's my problem.  I"m using this plugin (http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/) to autoresize my textarea when there's more text.  When I paste using keyboard, it autoresizes perfectly.  However, when I paste using mouse, it doesn't work.

So my code to resize textareas are:

```
$('textarea').autoResize({
    // On resize:
    onResize : function() {
        $(this).css({opacity:0.8});
    },
    // After resize:
    animateCallback : function() {
        $(this).css({opacity:1});
    },
    // Quite slow animation:
    animateDuration : 300,
    // More extra space:
    extraSpace : 40
});
```

My code to call the autoresize function on paste:

```
$('textarea').bind('paste', function() {
    $('this').autoResize({
// On resize:
onResize : function() {
    $(this).css({opacity:0.8});
},
// After resize:
animateCallback : function() {
    $(this).css({opacity:1});
},
// Quite slow animation:
animateDuration : 300,
// More extra space:
extraSpace : 40
```

});
    });

However, this doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: is `$('this').autoResize` a typo?  or do you mean `$(this).autoResize`

Comment: oops, it's (this), but still doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input) you need to use setTimeout on your paste event to wait a few milliseconds before you try to retrieve the value.

```
$('textarea').bind('paste', function() {
    var $textarea = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("div").text($textarea.val());
    }, 250);
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tAEmz/1/)

So maybe it might work like the following:

```
$('textarea').bind('paste', function () {
    var $textarea = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $textarea.trigger("change.dynSiz");
    }, 250);
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/W4zRr/1/)

Comment: try the updated jsfiddle to trigger the change right away.  Does it work for you on jsfiddle?

Comment: just modified it a little bit for dynamically added textareas - replace 'bind' with 'live' and now it works for textareas added with JQuery.

Comment: Be aware that the paste event is not supported on all browsers: Opera doesn't support it, and neither does Firefox 2 and earlier.

Comment: You could improve the performance of the textarea resize plugin and produce somewhat more consistent results with rate-limiting how often the resize formula fires: http://ratelimit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is that: plugin doesn't track paste events, it tracks only just keyboard events. Thus you'll need either to find another plugin, or modify that one (and track mouse events too).
Here's a part of code (of that plugin), where you should look for:

```
// Bind namespaced handlers to appropriate events:
textarea
    .unbind('.dynSiz')
    .bind('keyup.dynSiz', updateSize)
    .bind('keydown.dynSiz', updateSize)
    .bind('change.dynSiz', updateSize);
```

Maybe, add `.bind('click.dynSiz', updateSize)` there.
I'm not very familiar with jQuery and don't know, what such event names mean.

Comment: AFAIR, there's no `paste` event in HTML/js and this code won't work.

Comment: This is added by jQuery. There's no paste event in pure js (in all browsers).

Answer (score 0):

Super light weight:

Has anyone considered contenteditable? No messing around with scrolling,a nd the only JS I like about it is if you plan on saving the data on blur... and apparently, it's compatible on all of the popular browsers : http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable

Just style it to look like a text box, and it autosizes... Make its min-height the preferred text height and have at it.

What's cool about this approach is that you can save  and  tags on some of the browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/gbutiri/v31o8xfo/

```
<style>
.autoheight {
    min-height: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    line-height: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: none;
    width: 200px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('blur','.autoheight',function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    // The text is here. Do whatever you want with it.
    console.log($this.html());
});

</script>
<div class="autoheight contenteditable" contenteditable="true">Mickey <b>Mouse</b></div>
```