# jQuery on copy into input

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [jQuery catch paste input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input)

is there an event handler in jQuery for the event in which I paste a selection from the clipboard into an input field?

As for as I know there is no key movement involved so I would rule out `keyup` and `keydown`.
Click event would probably react as soon as I click to active the input field but would not get the contents as they are pasted after that event.

Any input much appreciated.

Comment: This has been asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input)
and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use the 'paste' event.
Here's an example, for copy, paste and cut for #textA

```
$("#textA").bind('copy', function() {
    alert('copy behaviour detected!')
}); 
$("#textA").bind('paste', function() {
    alert('paste behaviour detected!')
}); 
$("#textA").bind('cut', function() {
    alert('cut behaviour detected!')
});
```

Comment: Its not working while I checked in Firefox