# jQuery to trim() a text input field's value attribute?

Tags: jquery, validation

In this jQuery, I'm able to bind the paste event to validate the form field, but my method inside the function is apparently wrong. I'm not getting an alert at all.

I just want to trim the text that's input and return that as the value of the form input text field `#adsense_client_id`.

```
$("#adsense_client_id").bind('paste', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('value') = $.trim(this).val();
    alert($(this).val()); //why no alert?
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `$.trim` is a function which needs a variable/string inside it, since you did not wrap `$(this).val()` with `$.trim` in order for it to work.

As you need a timeout for the paste to be caught, do it like this:

```
$("#adsense_client_id").bind('paste', function(e) {
    var clientId = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        clientId.val($.trim(clientId.val()));
        alert(clientId.val());
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a9a6a/).

Comment: Makes sense, but I copied and pasted your code, and still no alert :-( Does not trim the empty spaces either. I'm stuck.

Comment: I can get an alert('pasted') if its the only statement in the bind function, so its definitely binding, even without a timeout, just not doing the trim.

Comment: you cant use $(this) inside setTimeout

Answer (score 4):

check out this response
[Catch paste input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input)

apparently you need to set a small settimeout to catch the pasted input value

this should do the trick:

```
("#adsense_client_id").bind('paste', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('value') = $.trim($(this).val());
    var el = $(this);
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        var text = $(el).val();
        alert($.trim(text)); //why no alert?
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).val($(this).val().trim());
alert($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question but this is pretty obvious...

The only poblem with your code is with this line:

```
$(this).attr('value') = $.trim(this).val();
```

Which is incorrect in JavaScript. I think you meant this:

```
$(this).attr('value', $.trim(this).val());
```

And the resulting code works perfectly:

```
$("#adsense_client_id").bind('paste', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('value', $.trim(this).val());
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```