# Is there a way to capture a clipboard paste event w jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

I want to trigger an event when a user pastes.

I have a contenteditable div and when the user pastes I want to capture the event and then focus back into the contenteditable div at the end of the paste which does not happen by default.

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery catch paste input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know, if this works cross-browser, it's working in Chrome:

```
$('body').bind('paste',function(){alert(1)});
```

Comment: For the cross-browser support I found an article on quirks mode: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the 'paste' event -

```
jQuery(document).bind('paste', function(e){ alert('pasting!') })
```