# jQuery bind to Paste Event, how to get the content of the paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy-paste, paste

I have a jquery token tagit plugin and I want to bind to the paste event to add items correctly.

I'm able to bind to the paste event like so:

```
    .bind("paste", paste_input)
```

...

```
function paste_input(e) {
    console.log(e)
    return false;
}
```

How can I obtain the actual pasted content value?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

There is an onpaste event that works in modern day browsers. You can access the pasted data using the `getData` function on the `clipboardData` object.

```
$("#textareaid").bind("paste", function(e){
    // access the clipboard using the api
    var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    alert(pastedData);
} );
```

Note that [bind](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [unbind](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) are deprecated as of jQuery 3. The preferred call is to [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

All modern day browsers support the [Clipboard API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard).

See also: [In Jquery How to handle paste?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160073/in-jquery-how-to-handle-paste)

Comment: This code will give an error on the `var pastedData =` line: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined`. You need to change `e.clipboardData` to `e.originalEvent.clipboardData`. I suspect because jquery is wrapping the actual paste event in an event of its own--don't quote me on that though.

Comment: `e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')` worked for me

Comment: in case you need it, the solution for IE: `window.clipboardData.getData('text')`

Comment: You can add event handlers to `paste` and `input` events, set a flag on `paste` event handler, and check for that flag in the `input` event handler. In it, the `this.value` is the value pasted, and this works in IE11.

Answer (score 21):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/5bNx4/

Please use `.on` if you are using jq1.7 et al.

Behaviour: When you type anything or `paste` anything on the 1st textarea the teaxtarea below captures the cahnge.

Rest I hope it helps the cause. `:)`

Helpful link =>

[How do you handle oncut, oncopy, and onpaste in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237254/how-do-you-handle-oncut-oncopy-and-onpaste-in-jquery)

[Catch paste input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input)

**EDIT:**
Events list within `.on()` should be space-separated. Refer  https://api.jquery.com/on/

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $editor    = $('#editor');
    var $clipboard = $('<textarea />').insertAfter($editor);
  
    if(!document.execCommand('StyleWithCSS', false, false)) {
        document.execCommand('UseCSS', false, true);
    }
        
    $editor.on('paste keydown', function() {
        var $self = $(this);            
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            var $content = $self.html();             
            $clipboard.val($content);
        },100);
     });
});
```

Comment: @Raminson Yeah I was `undefined` for few days innit `:P`

Comment: It does not cater the context menu paste(right click+ paste), any ideas on that?

Answer (score 11):

I recently needed to accomplish something similar to this.  I used the following design to access the paste element and value. [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zpdx4/)

```
$('body').on('paste', 'input, textarea', function (e)
{
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        //currentTarget added in jQuery 1.3
        alert($(e.currentTarget).val());
        //do stuff
    },0);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Another approach:
That `input` event will catch also the `paste` event.

```
$('textarea').bind('input', function () {
    setTimeout(function () { 
        console.log('input event handled including paste event');
    }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

On modern browsers it's easy: just use the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event along with the [inputType](https://w3c.github.io/input-events/#interface-InputEvent-Attributes) attribute:

```
$(document).on('input', 'input, textarea', function(e){
  if (e.originalEvent.inputType == 'insertFromPaste') {
    alert($(this).val());
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJOWxg

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#editor").bind('paste', function (e){
        $(e.target).keyup(getInput);
    });

    function getInput(e){
        var inputText = $(e.target).html(); /*$(e.target).val();*/
        alert(inputText);
        $(e.target).unbind('keyup');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This work on all browser to get pasted value. And also to creating common method for all text box.

```
$("#textareaid").bind("paste", function(e){       
    var pastedData = e.target.value;
    alert(pastedData);
} )
```

Comment: `e.target.value` might need `setTimeout` https://stackoverflow.com/a/1503425/577052

Answer (score 2):

You could compare the original value of the field and the changed value of the field and deduct the difference as the pasted value. This catches the pasted text correctly even if there is existing text in the field.

http://jsfiddle.net/6b7sK/

```
function text_diff(first, second) {
    var start = 0;
    while (start < first.length && first[start] == second[start]) {
        ++start;
    }
    var end = 0;
    while (first.length - end > start && first[first.length - end - 1] == second[second.length - end - 1]) {
        ++end;
    }
    end = second.length - end;
    return second.substr(start, end - start);
}
$('textarea').bind('paste', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var orig = self.val();
    setTimeout(function () {
        var pasted = text_diff(orig, $(self).val());
        console.log(pasted);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It would appear as though this event has some `clipboardData` property attached to it (it may be nested within the `originalEvent` property). The `clipboardData` contains an array of items and each one of those items has a `getAsString()` function that you can call. This returns the string representation of what is in the item.

Those items also have a `getAsFile()` function, as well as some others which are browser specific (e.g. in webkit browsers, there is a `webkitGetAsEntry()` function).

For my purposes, I needed the string value of what is being pasted. So, I did something similar to this:

```
$(element).bind("paste", function (e) {
    e.originalEvent.clipboardData.items[0].getAsString(function (pStringRepresentation) {
        debugger; 
        // pStringRepresentation now contains the string representation of what was pasted.
        // This does not include HTML or any markup. Essentially jQuery's $(element).text()
        // function result.
    });
});
```

You'll want to perform an iteration through the items, keeping a string concatenation result.

The fact that there is an array of items makes me think more work will need to be done, analyzing each item. You'll also want to do some null/value checks.

Comment: Could you tag what browsers this applies to please?

Answer (score 2):

I do it like so, this would work on most browsers used by humans

```
$("#couponCode").bind("change keyup input paste",function () {
   const value=  document.getElementById("couponCode").value;
});
```