# How to bind paste event in keyboard and mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: textbox]

I have three textbox and button which contains a unique URL. When clicking on copy button, it should copy the particular textbox value and I need to bind with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and mouse right click and paste event via jQuery or javascript function.

When I focus the cursor in browser address bar and when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> or `right click and paste go` event it should paste the copied url from textbox and go to particular URL.

So how can I bind paste event in jQuery/javascript after clicking copy button?

Comment: Is it `past` event or `paste` event?

Comment: i need to bind with paste event and ctrl+v .

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605415/jquery-bind-to-paste-event-how-to-get-the-content-of-the-paste

Comment: Mattp : yes i tried it but it's not working right

Comment: have a look at this http://text2clipboard.com/demo.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshman/7tqd05e6/) on how to do this in a input and textarea. Both mouse and keyboard events are supported.

HTML:

```
<p>
  <input class="js-copytextinput" value="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></input>
  <button class="js-textinputcopybtn">Copy Text Input</button>
</p>

<p>
    <textarea class="js-copytextarea">http://www.stackexchange.com</textarea>
  <button class="js-textareacopybtn">Copy Textarea</button>
</p>
```

JS:

```
//textinput copy
    var copyTextinputBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textinputcopybtn');

    copyTextinputBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var copyTextinput = document.querySelector('.js-copytextinput');
        copyTextinput.select();

        try {
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
            console.log('Copying text input command was ' + msg);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
        }
    });
```

Source: [Snippet from the answer provided by Dean Taylor with little modifications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/1793718)

You can bind the copy paste and cut events in jQuery like this,

```
$(".select").bind({
    copy : function(){
        $('span').text('copy behaviour detected!');
    },
    paste : function(){
        $('span').text('paste behaviour detected!');
    },
    cut : function(){
        $('span').text('cut behaviour detected!');
    }
});
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TFgNg/) on binding the copy, cut and paste events via jQuery.

- Both the key and mouse events are bound in the cut, copy and paste.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //textinput copy
  var copyTextinputBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textinputcopybtn');

  copyTextinputBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var copyTextinput = document.querySelector('.js-copytextinput');
    copyTextinput.select();

    try {
      var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
      var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
      console.log('Copying text input command was ' + msg);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
    }
  });

  //textarea copy
  var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textareacopybtn');

  copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-copytextarea');
    copyTextarea.select();

    try {
      var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
      var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
      console.log('Copying text area command was ' + msg);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
http://www.stackoverflow.comhttp://www.stackexchange.comhttp://www.stackoverflow.comhttp://www.stackexchange.com
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input class="js-copytextinput" value="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></input>
  <button class="js-textinputcopybtn">Copy Text Input</button>
</p>

<p>
  <textarea class="js-copytextarea">http://www.stackexchange.com</textarea>
  <button class="js-textareacopybtn">Copy Textarea</button>
</p>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: thanks for you answer 
but what i want , when click on copy button copy text which content one unique URL and when cursor focusing in browser address bar that time i wanna paste copy URL in browser address bar via ctrl+v and mouse event .

Comment: @RaviKavaiya Just try the jsfiddle in my answer. All the events you can capture using the jquery bind events. Both mouse and keyboards action are recorded. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#editor").bind('paste', function (e){
        $(e.target).keyup(getInput);
    });

    function getInput(e){
        var inputText = $(e.target).html();
        alert(inputText);
        $(e.target).unbind('keyup');
    }
});
```