# Trigger the keyup function when someone copy and paste

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a keyup function for multiple text boxes. How do I trigger the keyup function when someone copy and past something in to the textbox?

```
.on("click blur keyup", ".emotion", function() {
     //match something
});
```

Comment: DOWN-VOTERS: Please leave a comment as to why my question was down-voted. that helps. thanks.

Comment: There is a paste event available in jQuery:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605415/jquery-bind-to-paste-event-how-to-get-the-content-of-the-paste

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Switch the event `keyup` for `input`, which will trigger whenever something is inputted into the field, even if text is being pasted (both by pressing `CTRL + V` or right mouse button » Paste.

```
.on('input', '.emotion', function() {   
    // Do your stuff.
});
```

Comment: Are there any restrictions when `input` is used? e.g.: browser compatibility ?

Comment: [Can I use input event?](https://caniuse.com/?search=input%20event)

Answer (score 4):

This will do what you want:

```js
$("#editor").on('paste', function(e) {
  $(e.target).keyup();
});

$("#editor").on('keyup', function(e) {
  alert('up');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="editor">
```

Comment: thanks. `function(e)` - can I use something else instead of `(e)`? like `(a)` ?

Comment: Yes, you can call the event object what you like.

Comment: Don't use paste event. MDN states it is not fit for production in 2017.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `paste` event. As far as I've tested it works for Ctrl+V pasting, and right-click>Paste pasting.

Comment: Just add it to your function - `.on("click blur keyup paste", function() {...});`

Comment: You can also try bind function - `$('#this-id').bind('input', function() {});`

Comment: Don't use paste event. MDN states it is not fit for production in 2017.