# html input validation that works when using paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, input

I am using the following code for my validation that only allows letters and numbers and a few allowed characters.

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9%()#@-_& ]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
});
```

The only problem I am having is that if you copy and paste any un allowed characters then this doesn't prevent it. I know I have seen this done somewhere where it prevents the characters being pasted. Any thoughts?

Comment: add your code..........

Comment: add code on keydown or keyup of the input field having the validation

Comment: use $(element).on('paste',function(e) { // your validation code }) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035071/intercept-paste-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do 2 things:

1. Bind `paste` event (as is already mentioned above)
2. Fix your *regex* that allows characters in the range between `@` and `_` (all letters and some characters like `^`, `[`... because *you did not escape the hyphen*, and it creates a range `[@-_]`, which is valid (that is why you are not getting any error), but that is not what you expect.

[image]

Here is the fixed code:

```js
$('input').bind('keypress paste', function (event) {
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9%()#@_& -]+$/;
var key = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode || event.which);
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt1"/>
```

Comment: That's great! thanks for the explanation also really helpful

Comment: I wonder why people use "!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode" and not "event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.which". Or just "event.which || event.charCode".

Comment: @gornvix That was copy/paste of OP code, and 5 years ago when I was completely green in JS. `event.charCode || event.which` works as expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I couldn't get this to work. Adding "paste" just seems to prevent all pasting into the input box. It seems to me that the whole of the pasted string would need to be validated not just one character.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#textareaid").bind("paste", function(e){
    // access the clipboard using the api
    var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    alert(pastedData);
} );
```

or you can try this way [JQuery paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605415/jquery-bind-to-paste-event-how-to-get-the-content-of-the-paste)
There is one more way out, that you can do it so with `onChange` or `focusOut` events on textbox