# Asp.Net TextBox and capturing Paste Events via JavaScript/JQuery to Clean Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp.net TextBox control and I want to be able to capture a paste event, clean the text that is paste by the user and show the end result in the TextBox control. I have tried many different ways and yet none are working as intended.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="editor">...</asp:TextBox>
```

I need a solution that works in all browsers.

I am working with something like this right now.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var $editor    = $('#editor');

        /// Control used for testing, the control with ID editor will be overwritten 
        /// with the cleaned text.
        var $clipboard = $('<textarea />').insertAfter($editor); 
        
        $editor.on('paste, keydown', function() {
              var $self = $(this);            
              setTimeout(function(){ 
                    var $content = $self.text();             
                    $clipboard.val($content);
            },100);
     });
});
```

If editor is the ID of a div tag, this works perfectly but if editor is the ID of a TextBox control, this does not work. I get the old contents of the TextBox and not what was paste in by the user.

Can anyone explain why this above code works one a DIV tag but not on the TextBox control?

Comment: Can you please include the work you have done with text editing? Have you tried using regex? There's some [StackOverflow discussion on binding to the `paste` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605415/jquery-bind-to-paste-event-how-to-get-the-content-of-the-paste) that i think is probably relevant.

Comment: I have not done any yet since I am not capturing what was paste in to the textbox. Once I know I am getting the pasted data, I will use regular expressions to clean. Cleaning the pasted data will not be the problem.

Comment: If you find yourself listing tasks to be completed in a SO question, you should really *try* to do those steps before posting. Each of these items should be posted as a separate question if you're struggling to find a solution, but you should really give it a whirl and then post what's hanging you up.

Comment: @wahwahwah, It's exactly what I did, This post spells out exactly what the hang up is.

Comment: I edited your post to be more concise. If you have further issues with your project, please post each item as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Asp control change id on run time so you are unable to catch given id .

So to catch actual id:

Option 1.

`var $editor = ("#<%= editor.ClientID %>");`

Option 2 , use `ClientIDMode="static"`.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="editor" ClientIDMode="static">...</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I tried option 1 and it did not solve the issue. As for option 2, I already have ClientIDMode="static"

Comment: Yes, Uncaught TypeError: $editor.on is not a function

Comment: @MichaelBrown  `$editor` in your code is a variable, `.on()` is a jquery function - so `$($editor).on()`

Comment: jQuery version ?

Comment: I fixed the exception but got the same results. I have since found the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Bind to the paste *event*, and you have to set a timeout to ensure that the pasted values are populated. The reason is, the paste event isn't immediate (4ms) so the timeout forces the queue into conceptual order.

```js
$("#foo").on('paste', function(e) { // <---- e, event

  var pastedData = e.target.value;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log($(e.currentTarget).val());
  }, 0);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="foo" rows="20" cols="50">
I am a working textbox example
</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have figured out how to capture the pasted text, here is an updated jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var $editor    = $('#editor');
        
        $editor.on('paste, keydown', function() {
              var $self = $(this);            
              setTimeout(function(){ 
                    var $oldContent = $self.text(); // The old content in the control
                    var $pastedContent = $editor.val(); // Pasted content

                    // Clean data to meet requirements
                    $pastedContent = #pastedContent.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\s+)/gm, " ");
                    $editor.val($pastedContent);
            },100);
     });
});
```

Thank you everyone who pitched in to help.