# how to replace line feeds / carriage returns when pasting into an input element (like google)

Tags: html, replace, paste

I want line breaks to be replaced with spaces when a paste operation is done on an input (text) element.

For example if the following text is pasted into google search:

```
foo
bar
```

it pastes as:

```
foo bar
```

By default, text input elements will stop at the first line break like so:

```
foo
```

I was able to find a solution with a **textarea** element using the following code:

```
$("#textarea_element").bind('paste', function(e) {
    var el = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(el).val($(el).val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," "));
    }, 100);
});
```

But I would like to have this functionality on an **input** element. Any ideas?

Comment: Browsers have this functionality built-in because you can't have line feeds in `<input>`. Do you observe another behaviour? What browser do you use?

Comment: I think that soulution is here by sanitizing Clipboard data http://stackoverflow.com/a/687115/206502

Comment: @duri when pasting line breaks in google they are replaced by spaces: only with firefox and chrome, this is not the case with explorer.

Comment: this is actually browser behavior for all text input elements: firefox and chrome drop line feeds for spaces, and explorer stops at the first line feed. nothing to do with google in particular as i had initially thought.