# Jquery add comma to a pasted string in input

Tags: jquery

I want to add a comma after copy pasting string into input

```
$("#keywords").bind('paste', function() {

   var a=$("#keywords").val();
   alert(a);
  });
```

I tried the above code to check if the pasted value is passed into variable. In alert it is displaying empty value. How can i know if the value of the pasted string is passed into variable and then append comma to the variable.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9NG3/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paste` event is fired before the pasted text is available as a value property on the textbox. You need to wait a few milliseconds, and then just add the comma to the value, like so:

```
$("#keywords").on('paste', function() {
    var self = this, timer = setTimeout(function() {
        self.value=self.value+',';
    }, 300);
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v9NG3/1/)

Comment: Thanks adeneo, now it got it.

Answer (score 2):

the paste event here fires / triggers before the actual content is pasted on to the control, if you do a timeout and find out what value is before and after paste you can figure out and add a ; to the end.

i found a similar thread on the same here [Catch paste input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input) and you can find the answer too.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about this logic, i was not aware of this i.e paste event is triggered before the content is pasted.