# textbox value not retrieved on first attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to extract the textbox value and send it to server but when I paste something in the `var sd=$('#TextBoxUrl').val();` does not get the data on first paste event when I paste again then it gets the date from the textbox. What can be the problem?

```
$('.urldetailstextbox').bind('paste', function () {
    $("#DivUrlDetails").data('ready', false);
    divprogress.style.display = "block";
    DivUrlDetails.style.display = "none";
    $('#spandetail').append();
    $('#spanurl').append();
    $('#spantitle').append();
    var sd = $('#TextBoxUrl').val();
    $("#divlinksave").data('requesting', true);
    console.log(sd);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your html too..

Comment: Didn't you mean you've pasted in the urldetailstextbox instead of TextBoxUrl?

Comment: @graumanoz Or more importantly, just using `$(this).val()`

Comment: @graumanoz yes they are the same!

Comment: `$(this).val()` is not working either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to catch the paste event and wait a slight time to let the val be populated.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1503425/336542

```
$('input').bind('paste', function () {
  var element = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    var text = $(element).val();
    // do something with text
  }, 100);
});
```