# What datatypes does ngPaste handle?

Tags: angularjs

I've studied the API but it's very inadequate. Tried to search the net and played with the few examples I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454742/paste-event-in-angular-ngpaste), but it doesn't seem to be able to handle image data. Here's some testing code:

```
<input ng-paste='handlePaste($event)'>
```

and the controller:

```
    .controller('PasteCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 

      $scope.handlePaste = function(e) {
      console.log("handler", e.clipboardData.items.length);
      for (var i = 0 ; i < e.clipboardData.items.length ; i++) {
          var item = e.clipboardData.items[i];
          console.log("Item type: " + item.type);
          if (item.type.indexOf("image") != -1) {
              console.log("Image paste data");
          } else {
              console.log("Discarding non-image paste data");
          }
      }
  }

    }
])
```

With some text pasted it reports that clipboard.items.length is 1, with image pasted it reports zero length.

Is this how it is or will it change in the future, or should it be handled on some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works.
Tested with:

- Chrome v40.0.2214.115
- AngularJS v1.3.11

HTML

```
<input ng-paste="handlePaste($event)" placeholder='paste here'>
<img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}"/> {{ imageUrl }}
```

JS

```
.controller("appController", function ($scope){
 $scope.handlePaste = function(e) {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < e.clipboardData.items.length ; i++) {
            var item = e.clipboardData.items[i];
            if (item.type.indexOf("image") != -1) {
                var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( item.getAsFile() );
                $scope.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            } else {
                console.log("Discarding non-image paste data");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$scope.handlePaste = function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.clipboardData.items.length; i++) {
        var item = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.items[i];
        if (item.type.indexOf("image") != -1) {
            var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(item.getAsFile());
            $scope.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        } else {
            console.log("Discarding non-image paste data");
        }
    }
}
```