# Get clipboard data in ng-paste directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onpaste

I'm using angularjs 1.3.2.
How to get clipboard data on paste event?

This question is like:
["Paste" event in Angular [ngPaste]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454742/paste-event-in-angular-ngpaste)

But in this question, the angularjs version is 1.2.
And this is not working in angularjs 1.3.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uLLCre?p=preview) in 1.3.17, the main things to take in account are:

- You can pass the $event variable to your ngPaste handler in the view, which in turn has a method to get clipboard contents:

`ng-paste="processCb($event)"`

- In the event handler, clipboard data can be accessed through the getData method

`event.clipboardData.getData('Text')`

- .getData expects one argument which is the type of data you want to intercept, more on that: https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#widl-ClipboardEvent-clipboardData
- Also important: this is still a draft and all of this could become useless in the future.