# ngPaste on contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using `ngPaste` on a contentEditable div instead of input type text. However, I am unable to fetch the pasted content in the way mention in this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454742/paste-event-in-angular-ngpaste)  I am always getting undefined in my handler for `ngPaste`. Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div contentEditable="true" ng-paste="stripHtml($event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))">
</div
```

>

**JS:**

```
scope.stripHtml = function(content) {
    console.log(content); //this is always undefined
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fetch the pasted content?

Comment: Your AngularJS version? >1.2?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry. It supports editable elements as well.

Comment: No problem, any alternative solution?

Comment: I'm just trying. Can you share platform, browser version?

Comment: platform as in? Browser is Chrome 42.something.

Comment: Work in Chrome 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit) Linux  https://jsbin.com/tinesu/3/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: thats weird, its not working in 42. Let me check maybe something else is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

The Below Code (Modified from Sergey's) Worked in Windows platform, Firefox 43.0.4, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m but NOT in IE 11.0.9.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

.editable {
  background: white;
  height: 55px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 55%;
}

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

<script>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('sampleController', function($scope) {

    $scope.stripHtml = function(content) {
       alert(content);
       console.log(content); 
    };

});

</script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>AngularJS ng-paste within ContentEditable Div</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">

    <div class="editable" contentEditable="true" ng-paste="stripHtml($event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))"></div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But the function is getting called. If content editable didn't support ngPaste, the function handler for ngPaste shouldn't even have been called.