# jquery - On Paste, Getting input value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to get the value of an input of paste, but it always returns nothing:

```
$('form#post-game :input[name="header"]').keyup(function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    IsImageValid(str, "#post-game-img-header");
});

$(document).on('paste','form#post-game :input[name="header"]',function(e) {
    var str = $('form#post-game :input[name="header"]').val();
    IsImageValid(str, "#post-game-img-header"); // there is a console log in this function
});
```

The keyup works fine, But the paste does not.

Comment: Why you dont use $(this).val() too ??

Comment: `$(document).on('input','form#post-game :input[name="header"]',function(e) {/**/});` check for oninput event support. Your issue is onpaste is fired before the value of input is updated.

Comment: @FouadFodail Because i thought that might not have worked with .on, So i changed it to that.

Comment: @A.Wolff Ah thats, Working perfectly now.

Comment: May be val() needs time to get populated. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input

Answer (score 2):

Use the custom event afterpaste, paste method fires imediately some content is pasted, but some time s gives null value.

This afterpaste method fires  after 0 ms of paste method, and works fine in every case.

```
//Custom event After paste
$('HTML').on('paste', function (e) {
    e = $.extend({}, e, { type: 'afterpaste' });
    window.setTimeout(function () { $(e.target).trigger(e); }, 0);
});

//changed paste to afterpaste
$(document).on('afterpaste','form#post-game :input[name="header"]',function(e) {
    var str = $('form#post-game :input[name="header"]').val();
    IsImageValid(str, "#post-game-img-header"); // there is a console log in this function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on('input propertychange',` instead of `.on('paste',`.

Try this:

```
$(document).on('input propertychange','form#post-game input[name="header"]',function(e){ 
    var str = this.value;
    IsImageValid(str, "#post-game-img-header"); // there is a console log in this function
});
```

More info:

- MDN: [**input**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input)
- MSDN: [**propertychange**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) *(needed for older versions of IE)*

Comment: Responds to ALL property changes including keypresses. Not very useful if you want to take action based soley upon a user pasting text.

Comment: @AndroidDev, its delegated to `form#post-game input[name="header"]`, so its just for that input, how would you do it?