# How to see event.target in vanila javascript in a function triggered by "oninput"

Tags: javascript, html, events

```
<input type="text" oninput="myFunction(event)" id="i">

function myFunction(event){
    console.log(event); //can i find the keycode using this event?
}

document.getElementById('i').addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
        console.log(e.which)});
```

Sorry for the beginner question guys but can I use the event in the myFunction to see the keycode press as I did by adding the event listener to the element bellow.

Comment: Do you need keycode or target?

Comment: the target I guess. The keycode is in the target no?

Comment: The `target` is the element which triggered the event.

Comment: if i put event.target or event.curentTarget they are both null

Comment: @EmielZuurbier The target is the element that triggered the event. Ok so is not possible to see there the keycode, value, etc.

Comment: Unlike the `keypress` event, the `input` event doesn't have data that tells which key has been pressed. It is an event that is triggered when the `value` property of the input has been changed and doesn't concern itself about keyboard input. [`keypress` is also deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) and should be replaced by either `keydown` or `keyup`.

Comment: thanks, @EmielZuurbier for clarification

Answer (score 0):

i think that you cant get the key code in "oninput" event.. but you can do trick:

```
  let keyCode;
  input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    keyCode = e.keyCode
  });
  input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    console.log(keyCode)
  })
```

(from [Event.keyCode doesn't work with 'on input' - undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159930/event-keycode-doesnt-work-with-on-input-undefined))

Answer (score 0):

**event.keyCode** and **event.which** are considered to be deprecated and must not be used anymore, instead you can use **event.key**

Here's a working example:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="i">
</form>
  
<script>
 document.getElementById('i').addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    console.log(e.key); // will return exact pressed key
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
event.key
```

rather than `event.target`.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const showKeycode = (event) => console.log(event.key);
document.getElementById('i').addEventListener("keypress", showKeycode, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="i">
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

and **note** that `event.keycode` is deprecated:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key