# Allow user to paste numeric values either by ctr+c ctr+v OR by right click copy paste

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy paste numeric values in this field, can we achieve this keeping onkeypress as it is?

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" onkeypress="return allowNumOnly(event);">
```

Javascript:

```
  function allowNumOnly(evt)
  {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
     console.log(charCode);
     if(charCode==36 || charCode==46 || charCode==37 || charCode==39)
        return true;
     if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
       return false;

     return true;
  }
```

Comment: I believe the only way to do this would be to respond to the onchange event and check if the content was a number or not.  The keyPress, keyUp and keyDown events will only return ctrl and v not the actual numbers being pasted.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/catch-paste-input