# Remove excess words from a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script which is almost complete but I can't figure out the last bit here. The script is meant to limit the amount of words that can be entered into a text area and if they go over the word limit these extra words are removed. I have the amount of words beyond the max labeled as overage. For instance, if you were to enter in 102 words, then the overage would be 2. How would I remove those two words from the text area?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var max = 100;
    $('#text').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.which < 0x20) {
            return;
        }

        var value = $('#text').val();
        var regex = /\s+/gi;
        var wordCount = value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;

        if (wordCount == max) {
            // Reached max, prevent additional.
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if (wordCount > max) {


            <!--Edited to show code from user3003216-->
            <!--Isn't working like this, textarea doesn't update.-->

            var overage = wordCount - max;
            var words = value.split(' ');
            for(var i = 0; i<overage; i++){
                words.pop();
            }

        }
    });         
});
```

Comment: By the way, jQuery comes with a [trim function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/): `$.trim()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to approach this is just to count the number of words on `keypress` and go from there. Check whether there are more words than the amount allowed. If so, remove all the excess words: `while (text.length > maxWords)`. Then just replace the value of the text box with the updated text.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/ge9WJ/1/)

**JavaScript**

```
var maxWords = 10;
$("#myText").keypress(function (event) {
    var text = $(this).val().split(" ");    // grabs the text and splits it
    while (text.length > maxWords) {        // while more words than maxWords
        event.preventDefault();
        text.pop();    // remove the last word
        // event.preventDefault() isn't absolutely necessary,
        // it just slightly alters the typing;
        // remove it to see the difference
    }
    $(this).val(text.join(" "));    // replace the text with the updated text
})
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Enter no more than 10 words:</p>
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>
```

**CSS**

```
textarea {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;     
}
```

You can easily test whether it works by pasting more than `maxWords`—in this case, `10`—words into the `textarea` and pressing space. All the extra words will be removed.

Comment: Oh wow, this is so much more simple then what I was trying to do. Thanks a lot! Oh, btw, you left a ; out at the end.

Comment: @user1727423 Where? Are you referring to the end of the `$("#myText").keypress()` block? A semi-colon isn't necessary there, or anywhere, in javascript, for that matter (other than maybe `for` loops).

Comment: Semi-colons are required for separating statements and method calls (like the call to `keypress`), but not for function definitions. JS interpreters don't mind if you leave it out at the end of a line, but if your JS file were minified (as many are when deployed to a Prod server), then whitespace is removed to reduce file size. Then your code would produce syntax errors because of the lack of semi-colon(s).

Comment: @nbrooks minifiers typically do [automatic semicolon insertion](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=6), though, so… Personally, I tend to put semicolons after everything but function declarations, which, as you mentioned, are not necessary anyway.

Comment: @Luxelin Interesting! That I didn't know (although it makes sense). Either way I feel like it's a safer habit to just do it yourself rather than relying on that...if there were a bug there debugging would be a nightmare `:)`. I take your point though, thanks.

Comment: @nbrooks Another good habit (for production) is to start all of your js files (ones that will be used on the front-end) with a semicolon. This ensures that they won't interfere with one another.

Answer (score 0):

well it would be better to use java script so here you go:

```
var maxWords = 20;
event.rc = true;
var words = event.value.split(" ");
if (words.length>maxWords) {
    app.alert("You may not enter more than " + maxWords + " words in this field.");
    event.rc = false;
}
```

Comment: I'm not interested in using alerts. My goal is to remove the additional words over the maximum. Not alert that it is over the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You can put below code into your `else if` statement..

```
else if (wordCount > max) {
    var overage = wordCount - max;
    var words = value.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i<overage; i++){
        words.pop();
    }
}
```

And if you want to get your string back from that `words`, you can use `join` like below:

```
str = words.join(' ');
```

Comment: That's not really working for me. I play around with it and I just don't understand how to get the modified text back into the text area. I added your code to the original post to show how I put it in. I tried the str = words.join(' '); and that doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Comment: Hmm.. If you really compare my answer with @luxelin, you can see that both of use use `.pop()` and `.join()`.. Maybe you said nothing changes because in my answer I put it into variable `str`, not the `textarea` which is like this, ` $('#text').val(words.join());`..

Answer (score 0):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/7D5Er/)

You can use [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) to re-value the text-box. The array [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method will allow you to pull the first 100 words out of the array. Then just join them with a space and stick them back in the text-box.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var max = 100;

    $('#text').keyup(function(e) {

        if (e.which < 0x20) {
            return;
        }

        var value = $('#text').val();
        var words = value.trim().split(/\s+/gi);
        var wordCount = words.length;

        if (wordCount == max) {
            // Reached max, prevent additional.
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if (wordCount > max) {
            var substring = words.slice(0, max).join(' ');
            $("#text").val(substring + ' ');
        }
    });         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer I thought I might be able to offer a slightly more refined version:

```
function limitWords(max){
    // setting the value of the textarea:
    $(this).val(function(i,v){
    // i: the index of the current element in the collection,
    // v: the current (pre-manipulation) value of the element.

    // splitting the value by sequences of white-space characters,
    // turning it into an Array. Slicing that array taking the first 10 elements,
    // joining these words back together with a single space between them:
        return v.split(/\s+/).slice(0,10).join(' ');
    });
}

$('#demo').on('keyup paste input', limitWords);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2Dad6/2/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- jQuery:

  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).