# Amazon API Integration

Tags: wordpress, search, amazon-web-services

New to this site and the biz. I am trying to incorporate the Amazon API into my Wordpress site. When an ISBN # is typed into search box product info from Amazon database is populated. When I copy and paste an ISBN# from another source the search does not perform. Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an AWS question and is probably more a jQuery/javascript question. Your database lookup is probably using jQuery .change() event listener to perform the query when the search box is changed. This doesn't work very well for direct pastes, and a solution for that can be found here:

stackoverflow: [Catch paste input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/catch-paste-input)

However if you're using a pre-build wordpress site, chances are you have no direct control over how the search system works, in which case you either need to use something different or contact the original developer to ask for a fix.