# Javascript allow only numeric paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#txt').bind("paste", function (e) {
         var $this = $(this);
         $this.val($this.val().replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));
     });
 });
```

**Html:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

If value as below

```
10-10-20.0a
```

**Result** must be as below

```
1010200
```

I only want to allow it to paste numeric values to the textbox, otherwise, disable it. However, if I try the above javascript code, it is not working.

Where did I miss on the javascript side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the function on`change` event of Textbox as, instead of `document.ready`:

**HTML**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" onchange="onlyNum()"></asp:TextBox>
```

**JQuery**

```
    function onlyNum() {
      var $this = $('#txt');
      $this.val($this.val().replace(/\D/g, ''));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have your Client ID Mode set correctly, or the emitted text box will probably not have an ID of "txt".

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Another approach is to use CSS classes which can be very useful for re-use.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" CssClass="numbers-only" ></asp:TextBox>
```

And your jQuery selector would be:

```
$("input.numbers-only").on("paste", function(){  
    // do your stuff here
});
```

Comment: @Richard have you checked your emitted html?

Comment: Voted for pointing out the possible issue with ASP.Net's manipulation of the ID.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery event should be:

```
$('#.txt').on('paste', function() {...});
```

See example here: [Catch paste input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/catch-paste-input)

Note the use of a timeout to allow the value to be pasted before you manipulate it.

Once you properly handle the event and get the pasted value, you can add your validation.

Also see ste-fu's answer about referencing the proper field, as asp.net will by default append the container's is to your text box id and the selector '#txt' won't work.