# Append Alert Message To Element After Paste Action Gravity Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using Gravity forms on Wordpress. We have a text area that we have disabled cut, copy, paste and drop using Javascript.

We are using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var controls = $(".disable");
    controls.bind("paste", function () {
        return false;
    });
    controls.bind("drop", function () {
        return false;
    });
    controls.bind("cut", function () {
        return false;
    });
    controls.bind("copy", function () {
        return false;
    });
});
$('textarea').on('paste', function () {
 var element = this;
 setTimeout(function () {
 $(".paste-alert").append("<b>Copy and paste detected:</b> Please take time to write a unique description for your listing. This will ensure your advert will get found in the search engines and help keep Local Business a high authority, free directory. ");
 }, 100);
 });
 </script>
```

and adding a "disable" class to the textarea.

We also have a separate element:

```
<p class="paste-alert"></p>
```

When a user attempts to copy and paste in to the text area we want the text:

"Please don't copy and paste"

To appear in the .paste-alert element

Can anyone help, this is driving me crazy?!

Comment: Help with what? There is no specific question here and you haven't identified what is or isn't working

Comment: The above code works fine, but I need help to add the alert to the same code to append to the paste alert element.

Comment: do it inside the event handlers

Comment: I've edited the code with what ive tried, which works but it doesnt append after the copy and paste takes place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archieve this with:

```
$('input').on('paste', function () {
  var element = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    $(".paste-alert").append("<b>Copy and paste detected:</b> Please take time to write a unique description for your listing. This will ensure your advert will get found in the search engines and help keep Rate Local a high authority, free directory. ");
  }, 100);
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/me5dvwqL/3/

Source (best voted answer):
[Catch paste input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/catch-paste-input)

EDIT:

Final fiddle  after chat:
http://jsfiddle.net/n4hw4cer/4/

Comment: I undestarnd you question now. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi again, although your code works on jsfiddle I cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you bring the code of the input or something else? A fiddle dont working?

Comment: Can you post the html code of the element textarea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77969/discussion-between-juan-marcos-armella-and-alan-carr).