# How to check if email exists with jQuery?Working only when typing email,but not when copy-paste?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if email exists with jQuery, but works only when typing, when I try with copy paste than shows that email is available, but its not. Please see below code.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').keyup('check.php').show();
    $('#sign_up_email_input_first').keyup(function(){
        $.post('check.php', {email_sign_up: form.email_sign_up.value}, function(result){
            $('#test').html(result).show();}
        ); 
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['email_sign_up']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email_sign_up'];
    $select = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($select);
    if($email == NULL){
        echo "Choose Username";
    }else if(strlen($email)<=3){
        echo "";
    }else{
        if($count == 0){
            echo "Username is Available";
        }else if($count ==1){
            echo "Username is not Available";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure you trim any whitespace. Other than that you need to do some basic debugging. We can't do that for you

Comment: Also you should not use deprecated `mysql` extension

Comment: you only have `keyup event` for checking email.. you cannot handle paste event with that

Answer (score 0):

The reason it only works when typing is you're using the keyup event to capture input.

Comment: Depends what you want to achieve exactly. Maybe blur?

Comment: why not register onblur as well?
This way, the email will be validated once the user finishes copy and pasting and clicks elsewhere

Comment: I have changed 'onblur', but is not showing anything!

Comment: @K.Wayne See [catch paste input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/catch-paste-input)

Comment: @K.Wayne Also, your question could use some more work - I'm too lazy to do it for you. You should probably read the help center article "How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example".

Answer (score 0):

`keyup` is only triggered when the user stokes any of the keyboard input...
So when you use mouse events like copy and paste it isn't triggered.

try using `change` instead of `keyup`