# Auto Submit When Character reaches a Particular Number in a form isn't Working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This Code Works but when i copy and paste into it, it doesn't submit.

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<form id="Form" action="pro_add_invoice.cfm" method="post">
    <input id="here"name="htno" type="text" value="" />&nbsp;
    <input id="subHere" type="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>

<script>
    $('#here').keyup(function(){
        if(this.value.length ==10){
          $('#Form').submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: do you want to click after that the user typed 10 digits/chars?

Comment: @quirimmo I only want the form to submit, i.e going to the processing page.

Comment: but when? when inside the input #here you have a string with 10 characters? and please change `$('#subHere').click();` to `$('#Form').submit();`. The submit will occur when you type inside the text field a word with 10 character? Type this "abcabcabca"and it should submit

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded???

Comment: @quirimmo, i already changed that but that. I tested but not working

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of your example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you just want to submit the form after ten characters are entered. You can use `$().submit()` instead and pass in the id of the form.

```
<form id="Form" action="sell.cfm" method="post">
    <input id="here"name="htno" type="text" value="" />&nbsp;
    <input id="subHere" type="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>

<script>
    //$('#here').keyup(function(){
    //    if(this.value.length ==10){
    //      $('#Form').submit();
    //    }
    //});

    var input = document.querySelector('#here');
    input.addEventListener('keyup', checkLength);
    function checkLength(e){
        if(e.target.value.length===10){
            document.forms["Form"].submit();
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: It worked fine in my browser. Keep in mind you have to have jQuery pre-loaded.

Comment: Thanks. The last Statement Helped. i wasn't Loading the jquery file.

Comment: Cool. I just edited my response to show how to do it in vanilla javascript as well

Comment: I tried copying and pasting characters in the field but it wont load unless i type them.

Comment: Correct, this is because you are using the `keyup` function. It is only listening for when you release a keyboard key.

Comment: So, how can i go about it @wlh

Comment: Here's some more ways to research this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/catch-paste-input/1503425#1503425

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit the form you cannot use click event handler. That's only for click events. you need to call the submit method of the form element to submit the form.

Change your If statement to execute the following:

Vanilla JS:

```
document.forms.Form.submit();
```

or 
JQuery:

```
$('#Form').submit();
```

SO...

```
<script>
    $('#here').keyup(function(){
    if(this.value.length ==10){
      $('#Form').submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem here is `this` context is not belong to `#here`, the scope in the anonymous function (probably) belong to `window`.

I didn't try it yet but maybe this solve the problem, try change `this` to `('#here')`

Comment: Did you try it and verify that `this` was out of scope?

Comment: If you consist, here the [jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/8up4v32k/). Note: the reason I didn't verify it because i did't use JQuery, the test in jsfidle didn't use jquery but it just prove the `this` context is not belong to `#here`.