# Tracking Right click menu events?

Tags: javascript, menu, detection, right-click

Is there a way to track the right click menu when clicked over a textarea.

I would like to know if the user selected cut,copy,paste,select all.
Also, I can know when the menu is visible by detecting a right mouse click... But how can I know when it's closed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You may find this useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441631/how-to-detect-right-mouse-click-paste-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't. But you can replace the default menu with a custom one, over which you have complete control. Check [this example](http://dojocampus.org/explorer/#Dijit_Menu_Popup%201), built using the dojo toolkit.

Comment: If I use a custom a menu I won't be able to provide copy/paste functionality due to all (except IE) browsers security restrictions.