# jQuery textbox change event

Tags: jquery

Does text input element not have a change event? When I attach a change event handler to a text input it is not being fired. Keyup is fired, but keyup is not sufficient for detecting a change as there are obviously other ways of entering text into an input.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/jquery-how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed

Comment: Are you using $('input').change(function(){ do something }); ?

Comment: Yes I was using .change and .keyup, but they are not sufficient, please see my answer below...

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer.

Comment: See [$("#some-input").changePolling()](https://gist.github.com/2944926); for a wrapper that checks the current value and triggers `.change()` if it has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real solution to this - even in the links to other questions given above. In the end I have decided to use `setTimeout` and call a method that checks every second! Not an ideal solution, but a solution that works and code I am calling is simple enough to not have an effect on performance by being called all the time.

```
function InitPageControls() {
        CheckIfChanged();
    }

    function CheckIfChanged() {
        // do logic

        setTimeout(function () {
            CheckIfChanged();
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Hope this helps someone in the future as it seems there is no surefire way of acheiving this using event handlers...

Answer (score 29):

The HTML4 spec for the [`<input>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) specifies the following script events are available:

> onfocus, onblur, onselect, onchange,
>   onclick, ondblclick, onmousedown,
>   onmouseup, onmouseover, onmousemove,
>   onmouseout, onkeypress, onkeydown,
>   onkeyup

here's an example that bind's to all these events and shows what's going on http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/zJ7Lf/

I think you can filter out which events are truly relevent to your situation and detect what the text value was before and after the event to determine a change

Comment: I thought of using change, focus, blur, keyup and mouseup all together - however mouseup only fires if the mouse is over the texbox, this means it doesn't pick up a user pasting from a context menu where paste is likely to be outside the scope of the text input

Comment: looks like newer browsers support `paste` and `input` events, I added those after finding them here, [jquery - How to detect right mouse click + paste using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441631/how-to-detect-right-mouse-click-paste-using-javascript)...heres the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/zJ7Lf/1/)

Comment: potentially useful but can't use them really if they don't have very wide support!

Comment: actually, `input` seems to be the one-stop shop at least in IE9/FF/Chrome

Comment: updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zJ7Lf/288/ illustrating the issue with capturing programmatically triggered changes

Answer (score 23):

I have found that this works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').bind('input propertychange', function() {
        //do your update here
    }

})
```

Comment: I use it extensively to validate inline with ajax. I think the new mutation events being discussed will replace some of this functionality but this solution has been tested in Firefox, Chrome, IE 10 and Safari and is known to be working.

Answer (score 14):

The change event only fires after the input loses focus (and was changed).

Comment: If you REALLY want to know when any text changes, pretty much as it changes, you're stuck polling the input. That is, use setInterval with a function that compares the current value of the input to a previously stored value (via some variable with higher scope than the function). If the two values do not match, a change occurred. Then, store the current value into that other variable for the next check.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){              
     $('#textBox').keyup(function () {alert('changed');});
 });
```

or with change (handle copy paste with right click):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){              
     $('#textBox2').change(function () {alert('changed');});
 });
```

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/7DMH5/3/)

Comment: Check demo, its handling copy-paste too

Comment: Yeah it doesn't handle right-click pasting and then tabbing out

Comment: @PandaWood its perfectly working for your scenario. `change()` the second textbox will handle it as written in answer.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed yes. your adding of 'change' fixes that scenario

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed Oh, I see

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed Actually, perhaps what I meant was, I go to the DEMO link, paste in via right-click, tab-key off and the event doesn't throw - I don't get the message box for that on the DEMO

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#input').on("input",function () {alert('changed');});
```

works for me.