# key up and on change event for an html input type text not working for my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html input as,

```
<input type="text" id="txtCheckoutBCode" name="barcode" class="sfInputbox" />
```

Now I want to fire some ajax call meanwhile barcode reader reads barcode and the barcode is reflected in above text field.

I tried following codes,

```
$('#txtCheckoutBCode').on('change', function() {
    var me= $(this);
    var number = 0;
    number = $.trim(me.val());                        
    if (number.length == 12) { // 12 coz my barcode is of length 12
        //ajaxcall method
    }
});
```

But fires only when the focus is changed from the input field. Also ,

```
 $('#txtCheckoutBCode').on('keyup', function() {
     var me= $(this);
     var number = 0;
     number = $.trim(me.val());                        
     if (number.length == 12) { //12 coz my barcode is of length 12
         //ajax call method
     }
 });
```

This fires the ajax call twice, and I do not prefer this.

I need to call the ajax code as soon as the input field is filled with barcode. But not twice.

Comment: `self` is a reserved word in Gecko based browsers and refers to the Window object. Don't use it for cross-browser scripts.

Comment: whats the problem using  $('#txtCheckoutBCode').on('keyup', function() {
     var me= $(this);
     var number = 0;
     number = $.trim(me.val());                        
     if (number.length == 12) { //12 coz my barcode is of length 12
         //ajax call method
     }
 });

Comment: You mean, you don't want your function to be called at each keypress, nor when the user leaves the input, but only when a correct barcode is entered ?

Comment: Refer the jQuery textbox change event


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139954/jquery-textbox-change-event

Comment: For me, your code works like a charm. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/qL8HM/

Comment: @ZahidulHosseinRipon This fires the ajax call twice.

Comment: @RomainBraun yep only when barcode with length 12 is entered.

Comment: just change keyup to keypress

Comment: @matewka ye its charm for me too but when I use barcode reader to input text it fails to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use `propertychange keyup input paste` instead of `keyup` in order to be sure to detect any interaction with your input (such as pasting for example). But it might trigger the event twice, especially in Firefox. I'd recommend using `keyup paste`only.

`change`, as you said, will be triggered when the input loses focus. 
`keyup` will be triggered at each key press.

If you want your ajax call to be executed only once, try using **stopImmediatePropagation()**:

```
$('#txtCheckoutBCode').on('keyup paste', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var me= $(this);
    var number = 0;
    number = $.trim(me.val());                        
    if (number.length == 12) { // 12 coz my barcode is of length 12
        //ajaxcall method
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fC5yh/

Comment: I do not why but it fires the ajax call thrice.

Comment: @Jeetendra Well it doesn't here : http://jsfiddle.net/fC5yh/ Make sure you didn't bind the input twice, at different places inside your code.

Comment: In the fiddle, I found the code continues to fire the alert code twice.

Comment: @Jeetendra Really ? What's your browser ?

Comment: yep, really I am using Firefox version 25.0.

Comment: @Jeetendra Alright then just keep 'keyup paste' instead of propertychange keyup input paste

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40809/discussion-between-jeetendra-and-romain-braun)

Comment: @Jeetendra OK I'm on it.

Answer (score -1):

change keyup to keypress

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {            
$('#txtCheckoutBCode').on('keypress', function() {

                var self = $(this);
                var number = 0;
                number = $.trim(self.val());                        
                    if (number.length == 12) { //12 coz my barcode is of length 12
                        //ajax call method              
                    }
            });

});
</script>                       
<input type="text" id="txtCheckoutBCode" name="barcode" class="sfInputbox" />
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. According to jQuery's website : "As the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms."