# Can I know on PHP (without javascript) if a user has right-clicked oppening a link?

Tags: php, .htaccess, http

I was coding from some ideas collected over the web a "solution" to redirect all pdf, for example, downloads on a server to a reCAPTCHA form and, after passed, download the requested file. It is cms agnostic and works but I have one situation that downloads an incorrect file.

The code is at: https://github.com/Siot/docafi (request.php file)

I explain the process:

- All .pdf requests where redirected to request.php through .htaccess:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^(.+.pdf)$ request.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
  ```
- If it's the first time ($_SESSION var) request.php will show you a reCAPTCHA form.

  - If reCAPTCHA passed -> download starts.
  - If error -> error message.
- If reCAPTCHA was passed previously on the same session, download starts automatically.

The special case is when is the first time in the session but starts download using right-click over the link.

It downloads an incorrect file content because I can't show the reCAPTCHA form. Can I know if a user had right-clicked over the link without javascript? I want a transparent solution over the different cms/html files on the server.

Can I solve this on another way?

Comment: PHP can't know what the user is doing on the page unless you relay the info back.  (PHP just generates the page, from there it's browser-side processing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, selecting 'Save as...' in the popup menu works exactly as it should - it saves whatever is fetched by the link to local disk instead of trying to show it in the browser. It's thus completely correct that it's downloading the HTML file with the reCAPTCHA instead, and there's no way to detect it, not even *with* Javascript - to the server it's all the same, since the browser issues the same request, it just processes the result differently. You could set a flag on `onContextMenu` event, but it'd just have the wrong setting anyway if you then opened the link by leftclicking it or pasting the address in the address bar by hand.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible with javascript however PHP i'm fairly confident there will be no way this can be done considering it is server side.

Look through some previous stack overflow questions like:

[how to get right click event javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677941/how-to-get-right-click-event-javascript)