# How to handle an input text "paste" event with Backbone

Tags: events, backbone.js

I'm trying to send data to the server via `Backbone` if the users writes or paste a string inside an input text element.

in the Backbone events I thought something like this but it doesn't work:

```
events:{
    "click .close":"closeResults",
    "keypress input":"fetchData",
    "paste input":"fetchData"
},
fetchData:function (e) {
    var $this = this;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        if ($.trim(e.target.value).length >= 3) {
            console.log(e.target.value);
            $this.collection.fetch({data: {limit: 10, term:$.trim(e.target.value)}});
        }
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Is `input` located inside the `$el`? Because this is working example

Comment: btw `$this` is not an appropriate variable name as it implies that it is a jQuery object. `self` is a better alternative. Anyway your code should work I can't see nothing wrong with it

Comment: with this code `keypress` event works, but `paste` doesn't, I tried also a different `$this` name, it's a local variable, this shouldn't make problems inside this location.

Answer (score 6):

If you switch to using the `keyup` event instead of `keypress` and `paste`, it will work for pasting via the keyboard ( `⌘ + v` or `Ctrl + v` ) and typing normally.

If you use the `input` event, it will work even if you right click and paste (in addition to the same expected behavior as `keyup`).

More info on `input`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.oninput

Answer (score 1):

use keyup and mouseleave (instead of input) event handlers so that it will also work in IE

see also [How to detect right mouse click + paste using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441631/how-to-detect-right-mouse-click-paste-using-javascript)

```
events:{
    "keyup input":"fetchData",
    "mouseleave input":"fetchData" 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

**e.originalEvent**

```
_paste_plain_text : function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, text);
}
```