# Any html event for textarea similar to onpropertychange that works for (i.e. Firefox, Chrome)?

Tags: html, jquery, dom, input, jquery-events

In my context i want to call a function for (`onkeypress` and `onpaste` and mouse ~> click paste) but unable to handle "mouse ~> click paste"
so I need a event that handles `propertychange` for html input that works for all browsers.

Comment: May be this help, looks similar to your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/a/441647/2261259

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input`

```
$("input").on("input", function() {
    alert("Changed");
});
```

Seems to detect right click + paste just fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/WzZq4/