# jquery not triggering change when textbox changes occurs from copy-paste with mouseclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm listening to changes in a textbox using `keyup` and `change` as the events. This works when you type with the keyboard or do a copy paste also with the keyboard (Ctrl-V).

The problem is that when a user right-clicks on the textbox and pastes text, the change is not detected until the user clicks somewhere else on the page, and so things look broken. Here's the **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gLap0nv/)** and here's the code:

```
function Start() {

    $('#test').on({
    change: OutputTxt,
    keyup: OutputTxt
  })
}

function OutputTxt() {
    $('#output').text($('#test').val());
}

$(Start);
```

How do I change this so that a change that occurs with copy-paste is detected as soon as the pasting is done. Note: I tried adding a click event but it doesn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect right mouse click + paste using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441631/how-to-detect-right-mouse-click-paste-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try on `input`:

```
    $('#test').on({
        input: OutputTxt,
      })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; didn't know about the input event.