# Filter as you type tool with keyup, adding mouse and autofill actions

Tags: jquery

Simple jQuery code in place, but I'm missing some exceptions that break. With an input field that has the id of `filter`, when you start typing in the input it should do stuff. Works fine as follows:

```
$('#filter').on('change keyup', function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Here's the problem. If the browser auto-populates a dropdown and the user clicks an option or if a user uses paste from the mouse instead of keyboard commands, it's not picked up.

The 'change' doesn't fire until you click off the box, so adds an extra step for the user.

Is there a way to trigger the function from the mouse action of filling the field without needing to click off the input field?

Comment: another way is that you can do away with jquery event handlers, and place a interval (say 50ms) check on #filter. You still need to explicitly handle in doc ready the case where page is loaded with default value.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441631/how-to-detect-right-mouse-click-paste-using-javascript

Comment: @Ji_in_coding - I already have an interval delay in place. that doesn't solve the issue with using mouse inputs

Comment: @TH1981 the link maverick976 proviers, refers some good solutions

Comment: @Maverick976 - can't get the on paste to work. I've noticed that that question is a few years old and would hope it would move on to be easier. Also, he was asking about left click only - still doesn't solve the auto-fill issue

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may want to use the 'paste' event for this.

```
$('#filter').on('paste keyup change', function (e) {
var data = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
alert(data); 
});
```

As for the auto populate detection you may want to use

```
window.onload = function () {    
doCoolStuff(); //check value of input, etc
};
```

Which is straight JS.

Comment: The list is space-separated, not comma-separated

Comment: okay, that's triggering the function, however `$('#filter').val()` is still registering as blank. also, it's not solving the autofill question.

Comment: edits to include the variable change has worked! That's half the problem solved. Is there a way to trigger that autofill method?