# Detect if user performs a Paste using either key or mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to detect if user is performing a paste(Ctrl+V and mouse right click). I am able to detect ctrl+V but I can't detect copy paste from mouse. I am aware of the onPaste event but I need it under the keydown event because I am writing separate logic for many other key combinations. I have condensed this issue into a smaller code snippet below. I want the same alert to trigger if I copy paste using mouse.Thanks in advance

```js
$("#txt1").keydown(function(event){ 

    if(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 86){
        alert("copy paste detected");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt1"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect right mouse click + paste using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441631/how-to-detect-right-mouse-click-paste-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this answer meets your requirement.
May be you can disable right mouse button click by adding oncontextmenu attribute.which will prevent the right-click --> Paste action.

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
text
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txt1").bind({
    copy: function() {
      $('span').text('copy behaviour detected!');
    },
    paste: function() {
      $('span').text('paste behaviour detected!');
    },
    cut: function() {
      $('span').text('cut behaviour detected!');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt1" type="text" size="50" value="Copy, paste or cut message here" />
<br>
<span></span>
```

Comment: this is not intended result.